# Azure MVC Web Role does not use CSS when run under development fabric

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

When I run either application itself or Azure deployment from Web, my pages are rendered using CSS, but when running the Web role under local fabric, I get plain "no-CSS" style pages.

I have two questions:

- Anybody knows why does it happen?
- What is a good way to debug similar issues?

Comment: Are you saying that your browser treats the pages differently based on where you are running from? I don't think so.

Comment: I do not know why it happens, because of browser or because of the differences in deployment, but the local fabric deployed pages are completely style-less

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]
<sub>(source: [asp.net](http://weblogs.asp.net/blogs/anasghanem/various/IIS7%20static%20doc.jpg))</sub>

I had this problem and this solved it. Open up the Optional Features dialog and check off the option from the screenshot above. (You can get to Optional Features quickly by going to Start and typing `optionalfeatures` with no spaces.)

---

As the image is not avaiblable anymore: the following steps solved the problem for me:

- Open "Active or deactivate Windows-Features"
- Go to IIS, WWW-Services, Common Features
- Activate "Static Content"

Comment: Right on! Since dev fabric relies on IIS instead of ASP.Net development server, we ca see the difference.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this twice!  I had actually checked the IIS 7 settings using IIS Admin and found that a StaticFile handler was installed, so I thought this wasn't the problem. But I didn't have it enabled in Optional Features.  Enabled in Optional Features fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Run HttpWatch, Firebug, or IE Developer Tools, refresh your page, and you'll quickly see where the problem lies. It's likely just a pathing issue.

Comment: This particular problem cannot be spotted by running any debugging tools, because what happens is that if Static Content is not checked, the server returns empty CSS and not an error.

Comment: It may not have solved it, but returning an empty css would still have provided a clue.